# Residue of powers of a prime modulus another prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Given different primes *a* and *p* we know by Fermat's little theorem that

$$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}. $$

In the case of *a* = 2, a sequence for

$$ 2^{p-i} \equiv j_i \pmod{p}$$

can be written as

$$
    f(i)= 
\begin{cases}
    j_i = \frac{j_{i-1}}{2} ,&\text{if } j_{i-1}\equiv 0 \pmod{2}\\
    j_i = \frac{j_{i-1}+p}{2},              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

for $$1 < i \leqslant n$$ if  $p \mid 2^{n}-1$,
or $$1 < i \leqslant (p-1)$$ if  it doesn't, and if $i = 1, j_i = 1$ because of Fermat's.

Taking p = 11 as an example, $j_1$ is going to be 1, and since 1 isn't even, $j_2 = 6$ with $2^{9} \equiv 6 \pmod{11}$,  $j_3 = 3$, $j_4 = 7$ and so on up until $j_{10} = 2$ for which $2^{1} \equiv 2 \pmod{11}$.

With a number like $p = 23$, since it divides $2^{11} -1$, it's only going to have 11 values of $j_i$.

Since $2^{(p-1)n - (i+1)} \equiv 2^{(p-i)} \pmod{p}$ and given the conditions above, any power of two is going to be congruent with at most $n$ or $p-1$ number of unique $j_i$ mod p.

Now my question is if there's any way to generalize this for whichever different primes *a* and *p*.

Comment: This is very hard to follow.  What is $j_i$?  Is it $2^{p-i}$?   I guess not.  Is it defined to be $2^{p-i-1}$?  Why?

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a hard time making it clear. $j_i$ is going to be the value to which $a^{p-i}$ is congruent to modulus p, and its going to be different depending on the i, in this case the definition is concerning a = 2 so yes the value would be in regards to $2^{p-i}$. I've edited the post for clarity I hope.

Comment: Please include the definition of $j_i$ in your post.  As it is, it doesn't make sense.  If $j_i=2^{p-i}$ then your definition of $f(s)$ is inconsistent.  Why not include an explicit example?  Take $p=11$.  What are the $j_i$ in that case?  What is $f(s)$?

Comment: Should note:  Adding $p$ to the numerator doesn't change the expression $\pmod p$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have edited the post again and I believe it is now more understandable.

Comment: Ok.  But then, perhaps, $a=2$ is too special.  Since $p$ has to be odd in that case, we know for sure that one of $j_k$, $j_k+p$ is even.  This will not be true for a general prime $a$.  More importantly, though, what is it you want to do with this sequence?  For any $g\pmod p$ it can be interesting to consider the values $\{g, g^2, \cdots\}\pmod p$. but I don't know what you hope to get out of your sequence.

Comment: For any prime $a\neq q$ there will be some multiple of $p$ such that $j_k+np$ is divisible by $a$, if that's what you are asking.  So it is possible to generalize your sequence.

Comment: Could you expand more on your proofs of involved statements?  I'm having trouble following the argument without all the connecting language.